# Selector for a button which changes its background and text color

Tags: android, button, selector, onclicklistener

I am having a group of 3 button and want to change the color and text of a particular button when it is clicked and change again back to normal when another button is clicked.

I am using selector for the first time and I am not clear with the states either can any one help me out with this.

here is what I am doing.

these are my 3 buttons

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineartab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/allMessagesBT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/message_top_btn_selector"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="All \nMessages"
        android:textColor="#7b818b"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createNewBT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/message_top_btn_selector"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Create \nNew"
        android:textColor="#7b818b"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteBT"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/message_top_btn_selector"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Delete \nSelected"
        android:textColor="#7b818b"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my selector xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/login_edittext" android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_accept_normal" android:state_pressed="true</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_accept_hover"></item>

 </selector>
```

i want to do is change the background color once the button is clicked and keep it that way until another button is clicked

Comment: post the actual code to change text and color what you have tried..

Comment: I think you must do that in code with setclickListener for Button

Comment: when i click the button it changes its background for a moment and then back to normal but i want to keep the background changed until next button is pressed. can i do it with selector or i need to do it in JAVA coding

Comment: is there any way to do it with selector because i need this to be implemented most of the places

Comment: you can create one method that handle this in all class that you want, get one arrays of view as a parameter and one index for witch position must be changed, then set background or what ever you want for views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try As Devil Abhi suggested and also add some code as you required to change the color and text of a particular button when it is clicked and change again back to normal when another button is clicked.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.button1:
        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
        b1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        b2.setBackgroundColor(*default background color*);
        b3.setBackgroundColor(*default background color*);
        break;

    case R.id.button2:
        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); 
        b2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        b2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        b1.setBackgroundColor(*default background color*);
        b3.setBackgroundColor(*default background color*);
        break;

    case R.id.button3:
        b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        b3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        b3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        b1.setBackgroundColor(*default background color*);
        b2.setBackgroundColor(*default background color*);
        break;

    }
```

Comment: how can i change the text style??

Comment: @Dude text style of button??

Comment: by that i mean to say that i want to make the text of button bold on its click

Comment: just add this b1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);  inside the click event for the button.

Comment: @Dude see the edited answer to make the text of button bold on its click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RadioButtons or ToggleButton instead of button. In your selector you need to define background for state_checked and control you state in your code (for toggle button, not necessary for radio button inside radioGroup).

I suggest to use [toggle button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) and set checked false, when you press to another button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/relative1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="Red" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Green" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Blue" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
package com.example.backgroundcolor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    RelativeLayout rl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative1);
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.button1:
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;

        case R.id.button2:
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @blackbelt on simple button click its setting background

Comment: i dont want to do this in java file i want to do it through selector. is t=it possible through selector

Comment: do you want to use toggle button?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**radio_button_background_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
</selector>
```

**radio_button_text_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true"></item>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"></item>
</selector>


<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineartab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/allMessagesBT"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background_selector"
            android:textColor="@drawable/radio_button_text_selector"
            android:text="All \nMessages"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:checked="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/createNewBT"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background_selector"
            android:textColor="@drawable/radio_button_text_selector"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Create \nNew"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/line" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteBT"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background_selector"
            android:textColor="@drawable/radio_button_text_selector"
            android:text="Delete \nSelected"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```